# Unordered list inside table using FLWOR

Tags: html, xml, xquery, flwor

I want to make a table in which I'm going to make an unordered list with the names of the hotels and the number of stars like this:

Hoteles

---

· Macuya (4)

---

· Fuentevino (2)

· Tresarazos (3)

---

Using this code:

```
<vacaciones>
    <destino identificador="p023">
        <estancias>
          <hotel estrellas="4">Macuya</hotel>
        </estancias>
    </destino>

    <destino identificador="m036">
        <estancias>
          <hotel estrellas="2">Fuentevino</hotel>
          <hotel estrellas="3">Tresarazos</hotel>
        </estancias>
    </destino>
</vacaciones>
```

I tried this in eXide, but the names come together without spaces and the number of stars isn't shown:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Hoteles</th>
  </tr>
  {for $i in doc("/db/exercise/vacaciones.xml")//destino
  return
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>
            {$i/estancias/hotel/text()} ({$i/estancias/hotel/@estrellas/text()})
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to nest a further `for .. return ..` expression (and correct the attribute selection although I have simply used the `||` string concatenation operator):

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Hoteles</th>
      </tr>
      {
      for $i in //destino
      return
        <tr>
          <td>
            <ul>
            {
                for $hotel in $i/estancias/hotel
                return 
                    <li>
                    {
                        $hotel || '(' || $hotel/@estrellas || ')'
                    }
                    </li>
            }
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
      }
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks! :D Now I wanna put the image of a star right after the number of stars, between the (). I have no idea what you did.

Comment: Like this: `$hotel || '(' || string-join((1 to $hotel/@estrellas) ! '⭐') || ')'`?

Comment: I'm trying your code with an attribute now, and it doesn't show the names. Do you need me to send you the code?

Comment: Add any code to your question. If you select an attribute node with e.g. `@estrellas` you can't select any `/text()` child as your orginal code tried, as attribute nodes don't have any child nodes, instead, if you want the plain value, use `@estrellas/data()` or `@estrellas/string()`.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but how can you make like we did above and make an unordered list with attributes? Using, for example, the code I'm gonna show you above.

Comment: If you have different input data and can't adpat an existing answer to that data then it is better to ask a new, separate question where you detail both input, wanted output, current code, result or error you get.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this approach (incorporating @Martin Honnen`s great star rendering)

```
declare function local:render-destination ($desination as element(destino)) {
  <ul>{for-each($destination//hotel, local:render-hotel(?))}</ul>
};

declare function local:render-hotel ($hotel as element(hotel)) {
  <li>{
    ``[`{$hotel}` (`{local:render-stars($hotel/@estrellas/data())}`)`]``
    }</li>

};

declare function local:render-stars ($n as xs:integer) {
  string-join((1 to $n) ! '⭐')
};

<section>
  <header>Hoteles</header>
  {for-each(//destino, local:render-destination(?))}
</section>
```